# Layout of compiled objects

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, gcc

Is there a way—much like viewing the result of preprocessing with `gcc -E`—to see what my objects look like once compiled into object files?

I am talking about GCC, but a solution including MSVC would be fine.

Comment: Good point John. The constructor will be code, and like all code belongs to the class, not individual objects. Hence you won't find it in the object layout.

Comment: You can use `g++ -S file.cpp` to get assembler output in `file.s`.  Is this what you want?

Answer (score 32):

**For Visual C++:**

I finally managed to dig up the (well-hidden!) undocumented compiler flags that MSVC++ supports using information from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140826012851/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/349829/c-object-layout-browser) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2007/05/17/diagnosing-hidden-odr-violations-in-visual-c-and-fixing-lnk2022.aspx).  Here they are:

```
/d1reportSingleClassLayoutXXX
/d1reportAllClassLayout
```

(replace `XXX` with the class name)

Comment: Note for others who may land into this quest: This switch will output directly to build output window. So add it in .cpp properties 'Command Line > Additional options'. If your desired class/struct did not show up in the list (despite it is declared in header file), I declared a new class in cpp and make it inherit from that class, that did the job for me.

Answer (score 7):

For GCC compiled executables, checkout [Pahole](https://www.openhub.net/p/pahole). It will show you how the compiler laid out your structs/classes and whether or not they have "holes" in them. Holes are padding due to memory alignment rules.

Comment: the pahole link is dead

Comment: @ofloveandhate I fixed up the link.

Comment: related [Find holes in C structs due to alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674127/find-holes-in-c-structs-due-to-alignment)

Answer (score 0):

Object files contain binary data - the only higher level that most compilers can output is assembler, so if you can't read that you are out of luck. However, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129200/view-the-default-functions-generated-by-a-compiler) for more info in this area.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the layout of binaries and their contents using map files. Use [`/MAP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2%28VS.80%29.aspx) for VC and `-Map` or `--print-map` for gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing.

If you want to see the result of preprocessing with MSVC, you can use `/E`, `/P/`, or `/EP`.

There's an undocumented option in MSVC to show the data layout of structures and classes.  I'm having trouble finding it right now.

Comment: >There's an undocumented option in MSVC to show the data layout of structures and classes. I'm having trouble finding it right now.

this is exactly what i am looking for!

Comment: I finally managed to dig up those switches: `/d1reportSingleClassLayoutXXX` and `/d1reportAllClassLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor is just another function (unless it's in-lined). Object files contain a lot of info for the linker; so you should be able to find the function in the .a file (the function names will be mangled though).

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about seeing the memory layout of an object's field (as other answers seems to hint) then there is a visual studio extension that does just that: [Struct Layout by Ramon Viladomat](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RamonViladomat.StructLayout) (also available via [Github](https://github.com/Viladoman/StructLayout))

This will add a contextual item when you right click on a struct definition, that will open a memory layout visualizer window.

The display looks like this:

[image]

It has it's quirks, and I've been struggling to set it up correctly on some large projects, but when it works it's extremely useful.

There is also an open feature request ticket on the [MS developer community forums](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-tools-to-display-c-class-memory-layout/392536) to add the feature to the editor by default. Please upvote it if you want that to get traction.