# typecasting vs memcpy() : which one is better?

Tags: c++, c, linux, pointers

Suppose I have two variable as follows:

```
typedef struct{
   int proc;
   int id;
   int value;
   int last;
} my_struct;

struct my_struct dummy;
int len = 3*sizeof(int);
char my_msg[len];

//Some assignments are done here on those variables
```

Now, I want to erase the contents of `dummy` , by writing the contents of `my_msg` on it. Then which of the following is the better approach?

```
memcpy(&dummy, my_msg, size);
```

or

```
&dummy = (my_struct *) my_msg;
```

Comment: There is no `struct my_struct` in your type definition, so your example wouldn't work.

Comment: What would you expect the latter to do if it actually compiled?

Comment: `dummy` should be declared as a union.

Comment: &dummy = (my_struct *) my_msg; //wrong

Answer (score 6):

Your typecasting, besides that you got the syntax a bit wrong, has undefined behavior, because your struct may of different size, due to padding and have specific alignement properties. Don't do it like this.

Answer (score 1):

Neither, 
you may use xdr to serialize & unserialize or something similar

possible xdr library
http://xstream.sourceforge.net/

One more thing educate yourself with this too 
[Find holes in C structs due to alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674127/find-holes-in-c-structs-due-to-alignment)

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct{
   int proc;
   int id;
   int value;
   int last;
} my_struct;

my_struct dummy;

void main(){

    char my_msg[ sizeof(my_struct) ];
    memcpy(&dummy, &my_msg, sizeof(my_struct) );
}
```

When I develop network program, I transfer information by C structure. I can recover information this way