# Why do compilers (e.g. gcc) deal with the memory layout of derived classes in this way?

Tags: c++, gcc, object-model

Here is my cpp code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int val;
    char a;
};

class B: public A {
public:
    char b;
};

class C: public B {
public:
    char c;
};

int main()
{
    cout << sizeof(A) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(B) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(C) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program (in gcc) is:

```
8
12
12
```

This output confuses me a lot.

I know that the alignment may be the reason why sizeof(A) equals to 8. (`sizeof(int) + sizeof(char) + 3 bytes padding`)

And I also guess that the expansion of sizeof(B) (`sizeof(B) == sizeof(A) + sizeof(char) + 3 bytes padding`) is to avoid overlap when copy occurs. (is that right?)

But what I really don't know why sizeof(B) is equal to sizeof(C).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The sizes, including the paddings, are in bytes, not in bits.

Comment: Not related to runtime-debug prints, a VC++ compiler switch that ponies up the actual object-structural layout, vtables, virtual-bases, et-al, is incredibly educational. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138890/layout-of-compiled-objects) for details on how it is done for that platform. I cannot say with experience whether something similar exists for g++, but I would be somewhat surprised if it did *not*.

Comment: It might be instructive to print the offsets of the variables with `cout << "Offset of 'val': " << (int)(&((C*)0)->val) << " bytes.\n";` etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both GCC and Clang follow the [Itanium C++ ABI](http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) document, which specifies:

*... implementations may freely allocate objects in the tail padding of any class which would not have been POD in C++98*

`class A` is POD, so the compiler cannot put stuff into its padding.  `class B` isn't POD, so the compiler is free to re-use the padding within the base class layout for members of derived objects.  The basic idea here was that the C++ class layout should mirror the equivalent C struct layout for POD types, but there is no limitation for other classes.  Because the meaning of "POD" has changed multiple times, they explicitly use the definition from C++98.

**EDIT:** About the rationale.  POD-types are very simple classes that could be implemented as `struct` in C.  For those types the layout should be identical to the layout a C compiler would create.  In particular they want to allow C-tools like `memcpy` for `A`.  If `char b;` were within the padding of `A`, `memcpy` would destroy it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you explain what is this rule made for ?

Comment: I added some text to better explain the rationale.  Hope this helps.

Comment: What is the difference between ``B`` and ``C`` which makes ``C`` non-POD with respect to C++98? Both are publicly inheriting from a POD-class and containing only POD members. Or wait, is ``B`` already non-POD? In that case I just misunderstood the quote from the standard (in that case, some more context and clarification of your edit would be helpful).

Comment: @Jonas `A` is POD, as a result the padding within `A` must not be used.  `B` is non-POD, so the padding within `B` is fair game for subsequent objects.  But see the problem.  Better now?

Comment: So ``B`` is not POD, yet the compiler creates a POD-like layout? (being a bit confused here)

Comment: @Jonas No, it has nothing to do with `B`, it's the `A` they want to protect.  They want to allow ugly C-tools like `memcpy` for `A`.

Comment: Ah now I get it. I didn’t realize that for protecting the layout of ``A``, you might want to keep the padding clear of data. Thanks for your effort to explain that to me!

Comment: @jonas: The rule is more general. The derived class can never change the layout of the base class. The consequences would be horrible. So `c` cannot change the offset of `b` either. Only the tail padding is usable.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense, @david.pfx. I just had a hard time to realize why it makes sense to even protect the tail padding of ``A`` here (so that in C, you can ``memcpy`` over the ``A``-part of a ``B`` struct).

Comment: @david.pfx  Even more general:  derived classes can change the layout of base classes only if there are virtual base classes within the mix.

Comment: @pentadecagon: I don't see how. The offset of each member within its class must be preserved regardless of subsequent derivations. Can you provide an example that shows otherwise?

Comment: @pentadecagon thank you very much for your great great answer. I learn a lot. :)

Comment: @pentadecagon: By layout I mean the offset and size of each member within its enclosing struct/class. That doesn't change, and is usually quite predictable, even if not a _standard-layout-class_. Your example shows something different: offset of an inherited member. For non-SLC base class that's UB and for virtual not easily predictable either.

Comment: Re POD: actually the standard uses the term _standard-layout-class_. An SLC may have non-trivial constructors and certain operators, but otherwise behaves as the POD described here. POD is more restrictive.