# Methods with covariant return types crashes on VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14, clang++, virtual-inheritance

The following code seems to run fine when compiled with clang or gcc (on macOS), but crashes when compiled with MS Visual C++ 2017. On the latter, the foo_clone object appears to be corrupted and the program crashes with an access violation on the line `foo_clone->get_identifier()`.

It does work on VC++ if I remove the covariant return types (all clone-methods return `IDO*`), or when `std::enable_shared_from_this` is removed, or when all inheritance is made virtual.

Why does it work with clang/gcc but not with VC++?

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class IDO {
public:
    virtual ~IDO() = default;

    virtual const char* get_identifier() const = 0;

    virtual IDO* clone() const = 0;
};

class DO
    : public virtual IDO
    , public std::enable_shared_from_this<DO> 
{
public:
    const char* get_identifier() const override { return "ok"; }
};

class D : public virtual IDO, public DO {
    D* clone() const override {
        return nullptr;
    }
};

class IA : public virtual IDO {};

class Foo : public IA, public D {
public:
    Foo* clone() const override {
        return new Foo();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Foo* foo = new Foo();
    Foo* foo_clone = foo->clone();
    foo_clone->get_identifier();
}
```

Message:

Exception thrown at 0x00007FF60940180B in foo.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000004.

Comment: Have you analyzed the code dump? What comes from it?

Comment: Relevant for debugging this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138890/layout-of-compiled-objects

Comment: `On the latter, the foo_clone object appears to be corrupted and the program crashes with an access violation`

where does it crash ?

Comment: @UmNyobe I've updated the question.

Comment: it's better if you are in debug mode ....

Comment: @UmNyobe That was in debug mode, but it fails in some assembly that VC++ injected

Comment: `class D : public virtual IDO, public DO {
` 1) why the repetition of `IDO`? 2) does it make a difference if you don't repeat that base class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This appears to be a miscompilation by VC++. It going away when the `enable_shared_from_this` isn't there is a red herring; the problem is just masked.

Some background: resolving overridden functions in C++ generally happens via vtables. However, in the presence of multiple and virtual inheritance and co-variant return types, there are some challenges that must be met, and different ways of meeting them.

Consider:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo();
IDO* ido = foo;
D* d = foo;

foo->clone(); // must call Foo::clone() and return a Foo*
ido->clone(); // must call Foo::clone() and return an IDO*
d->clone(); // must call Foo::clone() and return a D*
```

Keep in mind that `Foo::clone()` returns a `Foo*` no matter what, and conversion from `Foo*` to `IDO*` or `D*` is not a simple no-op. Within the complete `Foo` object, the `IDO` subobject lives at offset 32 (assuming MSVC++ and 64-bit compilation), and the `D` subobject lives at offset 8. To get from a `Foo*` to a `D*` means adding 8 to the pointer, and getting an `IDO*` actually means loading information from the `Foo*` where exactly the `IDO` subobject is located.

However, let's look at the vtable generated for all these classes. A vtable for `IDO` has this layout:

```
0: destructor
1: const char* get_identifier() const
2: IDO* clone() const
```

A vtable for `D` has this layout:

```
0: destructor
1: const char* get_identifier() const
2: IDO* clone() const
3: D* clone() const
```

Slot 2 is there because the base class `IDO` has this function. Slot 3 is there because this function exists too. Could we omit this slot, and instead generate additional code at callsites to convert from the `IDO*` to the `D*`? Perhaps, but that would be less efficient.

A vtable for `Foo` looks like this:

```
0: destructor
1: const char* get_identifier() const
2: IDO* clone() const
3: D* clone() const
4: Foo* clone() const
5: Foo* clone() const
```

Again, it inherits the layout of `D` and appends its own slots. I actually have no idea why there are two new slots - it's probably just a suboptimal algorithm that sticks around for compatibility reasons.

Now, what do we put into these slots for a concrete object of type `Foo`? Slots 4 and 5 simple get `Foo::clone()`. But that function returns a `Foo*`, so it's not suitable for slots 2 and 3. For these, the compiler creates stubs (called thunks) that call the main version and convert the result, i.e. the compiler creates something like this for slot 3:

```
D* Foo::clone$D() const {
  Foo* real = clone();
  return static_cast<D*>(real);
}
```

Now we get to the miscompilation: for some reason, the compiler, upon seeing this call:

```
foo->clone();
```

calls not slot 4 or 5, but slot 3. But slot 3 returns a `D*`! The code then just continues to use that `D*` as a `Foo*`, or in other words, you get the same kind of behavior as if you had done:

```
Foo* wtf = reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(
  reinterpret_cast<char*>(foo_clone) + 8);
```

This obviously isn't going to end well.

Specifically, what happens is that in the call `foo_clone->get_identifier();` the compiler wants to cast the `Foo* foo_clone` to an `IDO*` (`get_identifier` requires its `this` pointer to be an `IDO*` because it was originally declared in `IDO`). As I mentioned before, the exact position of the `IDO` object within any `Foo` object is not fixed; it depends on the full type of the object (it is 32 if the full object is a `Foo`, but it might be something else if it was a class derived from `Foo`). To do the conversion, the compiler must therefore load the offset from within the object. Specifically, it can load the "virtual base pointer" (vbptr) located at offset 0 of any `Foo` object, which points to a "virtual base table" (vbtable), which contains the offset.

But remember, we have a corrupted `Foo*` that already points to offset 8 of the real object. So we access offset 0 of offset 8, and what's there? Well, as it happens, what's there is the `weak_ptr` from the `enable_shared_from_this` object, and it is null. So we get null for the vbptr, and the attempt to dereference it to get the object crashes. (The offset to the virtual base is stored at offset 4 in the vbtable, which is why the crash address you get is 0x000...004.)

If you remove all the covariant shenanigans, the vtable shrinks to a nice single entry for `clone()` and the miscompilation doesn't appear.

But why does the problem go away if you remove the `enable_shared_from_this`? Well, because then the thing at offset 8 is not some null pointer inside a `weak_ptr`, but the vbptr of the `DO` subobject. (Generally speaking, every branch of a inheritance graph gets its own vbptr. `IA` has one that `Foo` shares, and `DO` has one that `D` shares.) And that vbptr contains the information needed to convert a `D*` to an `IDO*`. Our `Foo*` is really a `D*` in disguise, so everything just happens to work out correctly.

**Appendix**

The MSVC++ compiler has an undocumented option to dump object layouts. Here is its output for `Foo` *with* the `enable_shared_from_this`:

```
class Foo   size(40):
    +---
 0  | +--- (base class IA)
 0  | | {vbptr}
    | +---
 8  | +--- (base class D)
 8  | | +--- (base class DO)
 8  | | | +--- (base class std::enable_shared_from_this<class DO>)
 8  | | | | ?$weak_ptr@VDO@@ _Wptr
    | | | +---
24  | | | {vbptr}
    | | +---
    | +---
    +---
    +--- (virtual base IDO)
32  | {vfptr}
    +---

Foo::$vbtable@IA@:
 0  | 0
 1  | 32 (Food(IA+0)IDO)

Foo::$vbtable@D@:
 0  | -16
 1  | 8 (Food(DO+16)IDO)

Foo::$vftable@:
    | -32
 0  | &Foo::{dtor}
 1  | &DO::get_identifier
 2  | &IDO* Foo::clone
 3  | &D* Foo::clone
 4  | &Foo* Foo::clone
 5  | &Foo* Foo::clone

Foo::clone this adjustor: 32
Foo::{dtor} this adjustor: 32
Foo::__delDtor this adjustor: 32
Foo::__vecDelDtor this adjustor: 32
vbi:       class  offset o.vbptr  o.vbte fVtorDisp
             IDO      32       0       4 0
```

Here it is without:

```
class Foo   size(24):
    +---
 0  | +--- (base class IA)
 0  | | {vbptr}
    | +---
 8  | +--- (base class D)
 8  | | +--- (base class DO)
 8  | | | {vbptr}
    | | +---
    | +---
    +---
    +--- (virtual base IDO)
16  | {vfptr}
    +---

Foo::$vbtable@IA@:
 0  | 0
 1  | 16 (Food(IA+0)IDO)

Foo::$vbtable@D@:
 0  | 0
 1  | 8 (Food(DO+0)IDO)

Foo::$vftable@:
    | -16
 0  | &Foo::{dtor}
 1  | &DO::get_identifier
 2  | &IDO* Foo::clone
 3  | &D* Foo::clone
 4  | &Foo* Foo::clone
 5  | &Foo* Foo::clone

Foo::clone this adjustor: 16
Foo::{dtor} this adjustor: 16
Foo::__delDtor this adjustor: 16
Foo::__vecDelDtor this adjustor: 16
vbi:       class  offset o.vbptr  o.vbte fVtorDisp
             IDO      16       0       4 0
```

Here's some cleaned-up disassembly of the return-adjusting `clone` shim:

```
      mov         rcx,qword ptr [this]  
      call        Foo::clone ; the real clone  
      cmp         rax,0 ; null pointer remains null pointer
      je          fin
      add         rax,8 ; otherwise, add the offset to the D*
      jmp         fin
fin:  ret
```

Here's some cleanup-up disassembly of the faulting call:

```
mov         rax,qword ptr [foo]  
mov         rcx,rax  
mov         rax,qword ptr [rax] ; load vbptr  
movsxd      rax,dword ptr [rax+4] ; load offset to IDO subobject 
add         rcx,rax  ; add offset to Foo* to get IDO*
mov         rax,qword ptr [rcx]  ; load vtbl
call        qword ptr [rax+24]  ; call function at position 3 (D* clone)
```

And here's some cleaned-up disassembly of the crashing call:

```
mov         rax,qword ptr [foo_clone]  
mov         rcx,rax  
mov         rax,qword ptr [rax] ; load vbptr, loads null in the crashing case
movsxd      rax,dword ptr [rax+4] ; load offset to IDO subobject, crashes
add         rcx,rax  ; add offset to Foo* to get IDO*
mov         rax,qword ptr [rcx]  ; load vtbl
call        qword ptr [rax+8]  ; call function at position 1 (get_identifier)
```

Comment: Well done!! I think the root cause is [Storage Location of Objects The C++ standard (section 1.8 paragraph 6) requires complete C++ objects to have unique storage locations. However with Visual C++, there are cases where types without data members will share a storage location with other types for the lifetime of the object.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/nonstandard-behavior). It seems wrong that  base class IA is at offset 0, and it is linked to this behavior. I didn't know how to link it to this particular case.

Comment: @UmNyobe No, that issue has absolutely nothing to do with this. There is only one "complete" (is not a subobject of another) object here, which is of type `Foo`. The subobjects inside are free to share the storage, as long as they're all of distinct type.

Comment: "_Could we omit this slot, and instead generate additional code at callsites_" How would that be even possible? The call site by definition doesn't know the dynamic type (or it wouldn't do a vptr call). The offset of the location of a virtual base VB from a given base class subobject S (that derives from VB) inside a complete object type is a known constant, but the offset inside an unknown type derived from S is **not even well defined** in the general case, as we wouldn't know which S subobject. So when virtual bases are involved, multiple entries are needed.

Comment: The problem of finding the address of a non morally virtually derived subobject from the address of the base subobject is analogous to find a container object address from the address of a sub^n member (member, member of a member...). A morally virtual base (from a derived class) is a base class that has at least one virtual derivation link to that derived class. The problem of finding a derived class from a morally virtual base is analogous to finding *the* object that contains as sub^n member a pointer^m to some other object. Many objects can have members which point^m to a given object.

Comment: Imagine a variant of C++ where you can override `virtual float f();` with `virtual double f();`. Obviously you are going to have two vtable entries in the derived class. And implementing that extension wouldn't even be difficult, as all the infrastructure has to there in any C++ compiler! In general, a derived to base conversion should be viewed as a lossy conversion like double to float. It's just a little more obvious if you think in term of number conversions.

Comment: @curiousguy There was at least one compiler that, for quite a while, allowed "co-variant" primitive conversions as an extension. -- Member subobjects are not complete objects. The definition is in n4687 4.5/2. But yes, for the purpose of sharing storage, the important question is whether at least one of them is a base class subobject.

Comment: @curiousguy Imagine three classes `Base` (with `Base* clone()`), `Mid : Base` with covariant `clone()` and `End : Mid`, also with covariant `clone()`. The ABI can be defined such that a covariant function slot in the vftable always refers to a function that returns `Base*`. If you call through a `Mid*`, the compiler knows, statically, either the offset from `Base` to `Mid`, or it can generate vbtable lookup code to do the conversion if virtual inheritance is involved.

Comment: @curiousguy One complication of this implementation approach is that the pointer-to-member-function representation must carry this information, because if I take `&Mid::clone` and call `(midptr_really_end->*cloneptr)())`, it has to call through the vftable, and that function returns a `Base*`, not a `Mid*`. But I believe even this issue can be solved with appropriate shims. I think the main problem is simply that it imposes a performance overhead on calls to the derived version that isn't necessary.

Comment: @SebastianRedl "_Member subobjects are not complete objects_" It appears that you are right and I am wrong. :(