# Use preprocessor to print defaulted functions in c++ classes

Tags: c++, c++11, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to have the C++ Prepossessor print the code for all auto generated functions such as copy and move constructors, along with copy and move assignment operators via a command line option to perhaps g++ or clang?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [view the default functions generated by a compiler?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129200/view-the-default-functions-generated-by-a-compiler)

Answer (score 6):

No, prepossessor is working on your source code, treating it as just a text, **before** c++ compilation starts and it does not perform C++ syntax analysis, it is unaware of any c++ language constructs.
The output of preprocessor, which is another text, is used as input for actual c++ compilation

Having said that, I want also to mention very interesting article that I read just today - [Can Qt's moc be replaced by C++ reflection](https://woboq.com/blog/reflection-in-cpp-and-qt-moc.html), which along other things also touches a bit question about *reflection* in C++ language and links to [Call for Compile-Time Reflection Proposals](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3814.html). So it looks like we just need to wait a bit and what you are asking for will become possible soon :)

Answer (score 0):

There is not. Not as C++ code at least. If you count dumping the generated asm, look at the `-S` switch.